# Integral of Sympy exponential function is non-numeric

Tags: python, sympy, exponential, numerical-integration

I want to integrate xe^(-4(x^2)) from x=0 to x=1. When i get integral result, result seems not numerical.

My code is:

```
import sympy as sp
def f(x):
     return x * sp.exp(-4 * (x ** 2))
x = sp.symbols('x')
integral = sp.integrate(f(x), (x, 0, 1))
print(f'Result of analytic integration = {integral}')
```

Output is:

```
Result of analytic integration = 1/8 - exp(-4)/8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type is an instance of `sympy.core.add.Add`. You can convert it to float by doing:

```
>>> integral
1/8 - exp(-4)/8
>>> float(integral)
0.12271054513890822
```